# Can the logic associative law be applied here?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$\big(p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)\big)$ is logically equivalent to $\big(q \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)\big)$

I am a little confused when dealing with the 'implies' operator $\rightarrow$ and the logic laws. 
To prove that these are logically equivalent, can I just apply associative law and be done with it? Or do I need to apply more laws?

Comment: Not exactly. You'd need to apply associative and commutative laws in order for it to work, but have you proved these laws already? Some ways of proving these equivalences are either by truth tables or by deducing one from the other in a suitable formal system. Was any hint given to you?

Comment: Well that's the thing here: associativity isn't part of the definition of implication, so *if* it holds you have to prove it.

Comment: @Nagase I drew up a truth table and proved it was logically equivalent but we are supposed to use the logic laws to prove they are logically equivalent

Comment: @joe - which logic laws can you use? Different systems have different axioms, so it'd be useful if you provided us with a list of what you're allowed to use.

Comment: implication, idempotent, commutative, associative, absorption, distributive, involution, de morgan, excluded middle, identity laws

Comment: @joe - Can you state those laws in your question? That would make things easier; e.g. are the associative and commutative laws formulated for all the connectives? Or just disjunction and conjunction? If they're formulated for implication, then you're pretty much done. Otherwise, you may have to use one of the strategies suggested by the others.

Comment: He is working with boolean logic. He really should not have to define the axioms for you.

Comment: @ChantryCargill - There are several axiom systems for the propositional calculus, depending on which connectives you take as primitive (compare, e.g., Shoenfield's axioms, which take disjunction and negation as primitive, with, say, Mendelson's, which take impliction and negation). If we don't know which axioms he's using, we don't know which equivalences he's allowed to use.

Comment: @Nagase I'm under the impression that he's not doing graduate level work here ...

Comment: @ChantryCargill - Me neither. That's why I asked which axiom system he's using. If he was doing graduate level work, it'd be obvious that he could employ any method to prove the equivalences, including truth tables. But he said that he had already proven the equivalences using truth tables, whence I'm guessing he was asked to prove them using a given proof system. If we don't know which proof system it is, it's hard to give more precise hints.

Comment: There is no associative law for implication in two-valued logic.

Comment: Thank you for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $P \rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\neg P \vee Q$, you can eliminate all implications and use the fact that $\vee$ is associative.

$p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$

$\neg p \vee (q\rightarrow r)$

$\neg p \vee (\neg q \vee r)$

$(\neg p \vee \neg q) \vee r \quad$ by associativity

$(\neg q \vee \neg p) \vee r \quad$ by commutativity

Do the same to $q \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ to get $(\neg q \vee \neg p) \vee r$.

Comment: Does it matter that the propositions are negative? If I show that -q v (-p v r) ==  -p v (-q v r) ?

Comment: Your two statements are equivalent because $\vee$ is both associative and commutative. In other words, the first statement is $(\neg q) \vee (\neg p) \vee r$, while the second one is $(\neg p) \vee (\neg q) \vee r$, so they are equivalent.

Comment: This proof comes as quite local.  A more general proof could involve using the infinite-valued logic axioms CpCqp, CCpqCCqrCpr, CCNpNqCqp, CCCpqqCCqpp, under detachment and uniform substitution and then proving CCpCqrCqCpr.  Since those axioms hold as theorems in both infinite-valued logic and two-valued logic, such a proof works for both systems.

Comment: The last step  -p V -q V r what law is this? is it distributive?

Comment: @joe: explanation added in last two steps.

Answer (score 6):

First, associativity fails to hold for a chain of implications:

$$p\rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \not \equiv (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$$

Rather, what we can use is the following equivalence $$p \rightarrow (q\rightarrow r) \iff (p\land q) \rightarrow r$$  This equivalence is a valid rule of replacement in propositional logic, and is known as [importation/exportation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)), depending on the direction of the biconditional that is being cited.

Using this equivalence, a very concise proof of your equivalence follows:

$$\begin{align} \big(p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)\big) & \equiv (p\land q) \rightarrow r \tag{1}\\ 
& \equiv (q\land p) \rightarrow r\tag{2}\\
&\equiv q\rightarrow(p \rightarrow r)\tag{3}
\end{align}$$

$(1),\; (3)$ by importation,exportation,

$(2)$ by the commutativity of $\land$.

Comment: This is also kind of local.  The equivalence used here fails in Wajsberg-Lukasiewicz three-valued logic, even though (p→(q→r)) is equivalent to (q→(p→r)) there.

Comment: :) I came across your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome, @Avra!  Glad you liked it.

Answer (score 3):

$\neg p \vee (\neg q \vee r) \equiv \neg p \vee \neg q \vee r \equiv \neg q \vee \neg p \vee r \equiv \neg q \vee (\neg p \vee r)
$

The key is that a implies b is the same as not a or b.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit? If we're working with a propositional calculus, it's not clear what the equal sign means, as those formulas are obviously not equal. Perhaps you mean they're equivalent? But that's precisely what one has to *prove* here...

Comment: I'm saying equivalent. I feel like that should be obvious. I simply converted the implies operator to another easier to work with form.

Comment: Not really sure why I got a neg for a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your logic laws include $a\rightarrow(b\rightarrow c)\equiv (a\wedge b)\rightarrow c$ (which is in fact a correct logical equivalence, called the law of importation), that could be another approach.

Answer (score 1):

> $\big(p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)\big)$ is logically equivalent to $\big(q \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)\big)$

Hint for alternative proof suggestion:

'$\to$'

1. $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ (Premise)
2. $q$ (Premise)
3. $p$ (Premise)
4. $q \rightarrow r$ (Detachment, 1, 3)

etc.